# Force app to stay active

Tags: ram, background-process

My phone has very low memory (2 GB of ram) and thus any app that is running in background is automatically closed after a minute or so. It appears in the task manager but when I open it, the app doesn't resume but rather starts up again.

However, apps like zoom or WhatsApp calls are not subject to the same background limit.

My question is, can I force other apps to stay active as well?

Comment: I have seen this question https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/keep-the-home-launcher-from-being-killed but it doesn't seem to answer how to do it for non OS tasks